# Attempted to assign to readonly property error

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am trying to nest a stack navigation inside a drawer navigation and I get

```
Device: (895:881) Attempted to assign to readonly property.
Evaluating module://react-native-screens.js
Evaluating module://react-navigation-drawer.js
Evaluating module://routes/drawer.js.js
Evaluating module://App.js.js
Loading module://App.js
```

The Drawer nests two stack navigators. homeStack and drawerStack. Drawer is the exported in App.js. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Drawer.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeStack from './homeStack';
import DrawerStack from './drawerStack';

const screens = {

  Home: {
  screen: HomeStack,
},
  About: {
  screen: DrawerStack,
}}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(screens);
export default Drawer;
```

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Drawer from './routes/drawer'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
      <Drawer /> 
);
}
}
```

Comment: Is this on snack.expo.io? Try removing everything from package.json and then add them back

Comment: it is on snack expo yes. But now it doesn't load the app at all.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: I made a change but I get a different error.    https://snack.expo.io/@andreeam/it-in-the-valley

Comment: I spent so much time on this, but I just can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: I think it'll be better if you create a new snack and try there. I tried to fix it but there are many syntax errors and wrong file names